# Create Boxplot Grouped By Column

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, that has a `price` column and a `year` column.  I want to create a boxplot after grouping the rows based on their `year`.  Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame({"year":[2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013],
                     "price":[190, 270, 330, 225, 138, 92, 76, 190, 110, 140, 160, 180, 170]})

    price   year
0   190 2011
1   270 2011
2   330 2011
3   225 2011
4   138 2012
5   92  2012
6   76  2012
7   190 2012
8   110 2013
9   140 2013
10  160 2013
11  180 2013
12  170 2013
```

So in this case, I'd want a boxplot for each of 2011, 2012, and 2013 based on their `price` column.  I've looked into `DataFrame.groupby` but it produces a different object (a group by object).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
temp.boxplot("price", by="year")
```

is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: If somebody like me wants to remove the "Boxplot group by year", it can be removed by setting: `plt.suptitle('')`